# apt-get install vs pip install

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, pip

I am a bit confused about the cases in which the above commands must be used when downloading python packages. I was trying to download a package named pyudev in accordance with an answer with this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages). I executed this command :

```
sudo pip install python-pyudev
```

but received the following message :

```
Downloading/unpacking python-pyudev

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-pyudev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-pyudev
Storing complete log in /home/vineet/.pip/pip.log
```

However the following worked fine :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyudev
```

When is `apt-get` supposed to be used to install packages and when is `python-pip` used?

Comment: `pip` is used to install python packages only, but `apt-get` is used to install all the any package.

Comment: ok..so why wasn't pip able to install python-pyudev?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874527/difference-in-installing-a-package-using-pip-and-apt-get

Answer (score 131, accepted):

[PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) is the Python Package index — repository of python modules.

`pip` is used to download and install packages directly from PyPI. PyPI is hosted by [Python Software Foundation](http://www.python.org/psf). It is a specialized package manager that only deals with python packages.

`apt-get` is used to download and install packages from Ubuntu repositories which are hosted by Canonical.

Some of the differences between installing python packages from `apt-get` and `pip` are as follows:

- Canonical only provides packages for selected python modules. Whereas, PyPI hosts a much broader range of python modules. So, there are a lot of python modules which you won't be able to install using `apt-get`.
- Canonical only hosts a single version of any package (generally the latest or the one released in recent past). So, with `apt-get` we cannot decide the version of python-package that we want. `pip` helps us in this situation. We can install any version of the package that has previously been uploaded on PyPI. This is extremely helpful in case of conflict in dependencies.
- `apt-get` installs python modules in system-wide location. We cannot just install modules in our project [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). `pip` solves this problem for us. If we are using `pip` after activating the virtualenv, it is intelligent enough to only install the modules in our project virtualenv. As mentioned in previous point, if there is a version of a particular python package already installed in system-wide location, and one of our project requires an older version of the same python package, in such situations we can use virtualenv and pip to install that older version of python package without any conflicts.
- As [@Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu) pointed out [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/431792/114818), there would generally be difference in names of packages as well. Canonical usually names Python 2 packages as `python-<package_name>` and Python 3 packages as `python3-<package_name>`. Whereas for `pip` we generally just need to use `<package_name>` for both Python 2 as well as Python3 packages.

### Which one should you use:

Both `apt-get` and `pip` are mature package managers which automatically install any other package dependency while installing. You may use anyone as you like. However, if you need to install a particular version of python-package, or install the package in a virtualenv, or install a package which is only hosted on PyPI; only `pip` would help you solve that issue. Otherwise, if you don't mind installing the packages in system-wide location it doesn't really matter whether you use `apt-get` or `pip`.

Comment: Also, you should attempt to use *one or the other*, and not both `pip` and `apt-get` simutaneously.

Comment: Sooner or later, one may need a package or a version thereof that is not provided by `apt-get`. Because using both `apt-get` and `pip` may cause conflicts, should the advice be to always use `pip` for packages supported by `pip`?

Comment: @Abhishek, my preferred method is to always use Python through a virtualenv.. So, yes, I prefer to use pip over apt..

Comment: That opens its own can of worms in certain scenarios. Let's say you installed most of your packages with `sudo pip` without `virtualenv` because most of your projects needed the same environment (but more extensive than what's provided with clean Ubuntu installation). Then  when you do a system upgrade and Ubuntu decides to upgrade Python to a new version (like with `zesty` to `artful` - Python 3.5 to 3.6), all of your pip-installed packages in `/usr` are left behind and `pip.get_installed_distributions()` produces an empty list.

Comment: Using pip in global context is plain wrong and must not be used, because it will mess up system python installation. pip and apt-get a completely different things, and it is wrong to compare them. Try to install a python module which depends on other non-python libraries and you will quickly realise why you might need apt-get.

Comment: Will **snap** play a role in these packages in the future, maybe 2021?

Comment: @Timo I don't think so. Two cases: a.) Developer for other os-platform may not distribute a snap package but a unix install script with pip command or apt. b.) If all Distributon software in python comes as snap package this may give dependency on snap. Some people may not like this. Finally I think you still have to be aware of the problem and analyse the distribution process for third party software.

Answer (score 22):

As @AvinashRaj said in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install#comment560650_431780), `pip` is used to install python packages only, but `apt-get` is used to install packages created in any programming language.

Your main problem is to find the right package name in both cases:

```
pip search pyudev
```

will give you the right name for the package you want to install using `pip install`, as

```
apt-cache search pyudev
```

will give you the right name for the package you want to install using `apt-get install`:

```
radu@Radu: ~ $ pip search pyudev
pyudev                    - A libudev binding
radu@Radu: ~ $ apt-cache search pyudev
python-pyudev - Python bindings for libudev
python3-pyudev - Python3 bindings for libudev
```

So, in conlusion, the correspondent of `sudo apt-get install python-pyudev` is `sudo pip install pyudev`, not `sudo pip install python-pyudev`.

Now depends on you what you want to choose when you want to install a python package: `pip` or `apt-get`. See for example [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874527/difference-in-installing-a-package-using-pip-and-apt-get) about difference in installing a package using `pip` and `apt-get`.

Comment: As @mestia commented on the accepted answer, `sudo pip install ...` is likely to cause problems.

Comment: This is entirely useless advice, when a python script has requirement "flask", for example, and I do an "apt-cache search flask", you should see what the response is. I get to choose from about 200 python flask entries, and have no clue which one is required.

Answer (score 8):

This is the advice given on a widely linked [issue on the GitHub pip site](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) on the subject of *system installed pip* vs *local installed pip*:

> 1. **Only ever use your system package manager to upgrade the system pip**. The system installed pip is owned by the distribution, and if
>    you don't use distribution-supplied tools to manage it, you will hit
>    problems. Yes, we know pip says "you should upgrade with pip install
>    -U pip" - that's true in a pip-managed installation, ideally distributions should patch this message to give appropriate
>    instructions in the system pip, but they don't. We're working with
>    them on this, but it's not going to happen soon (remember, we're
>    looking at cases where people are upgrading old versions of pip here,
>    so patches to new versions won't help).
> 2. **Never use sudo with pip**. This follows on from the first point. If you think you need to use sudo, you're probably trying to modify a
>    distribution-owned file. See point 1.
> 3. **Prefer to use --user**. By doing this, you only ever install packages in your personal directories, and so you avoid interfering
>    with the system copy of pip. But there are PATH issues you need to be
>    aware of here. We'll cover these later. Put simply, it's possible to
>    follow this advice, and still hit problems, because you're not
>    actually running the wrapper you installed as --user.

Answer (score 6):

My preferred way is to always use `apt` and only in case the module is not yet available in Debian/Ubuntu repository to use `pip`, but only in user context - `--user` flag. By using `pip` one anyway have to get all the build-dependencies installed from let's say Ubuntu's repository or provide them themselves which can be a tedious task. `apt-get` install binary packages while `pip` builds them after downloading. One shouldn't use pip to install modules into system locations. This is plain wrong. Always use `--user` flag to install a module to home location. Properly configured PYTHONPATH let python to pick up the modules from the HOME first and then system modules installed with `apt-get`.