# Terminal states ipython not installed despite being installed

Tags: dpkg, pip, ipython

I installed `ipython` using `python-pip`. Here is the traceback :

```
user@MY-PC:~$ sudo pip install ipython
[sudo] password for user: 
Downloading/unpacking ipython
  Downloading ipython-2.3.0-py27-none-any.whl (2.8MB): 2.8MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: ipython
Successfully installed ipython
Cleaning up...
```

However when I ran the `dpkg -s` and `dpkg -l` commands to check the version the terminal gave
the following outputs :

```
user@MY-PC:~$ dpkg -s ipython | grep Version
dpkg-query: package 'ipython' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

user@MY-PC:~$ dpkg -l ipython
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  ipython        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

What is wrong here and how do I verify my installation of `ipython` and check its version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apt-get install vs pip install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install)

Comment: That question could be used as a reference in an answer but I don't think this question qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: I think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install ipython`. I think the pip command is for python itself (installing module, etc.) and not for installing a system program, just speculation,not sure of it.

Maybe try

```
python ipython
```

Or `python` then `import ipython` or `ipython`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/431780/256099

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `apt-get`.`ipython` is a shell not a module. So ran `ipython` directly and verified it.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed it as source package, the goal is to use it as a library on your code.

In order to check it, enter `python` in a terminal to open a shell and try to import it:

```
import ipython
```

If you get none errors, it means everything is alright. An example:

```
>>> import os # This package exist and it's installed!
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> import bottle # This package exist but it's not installed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bottle
>>> bottle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bottle' is not defined
```

It happens to be that your specified package provides *interactive Python shells terminal based* (read [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython)) so you can use it from your terminal running `ipython` as any other command.

This is a very specific case and does not apply to every python package.

More information on [apt-get install vs pip install](https://askubuntu.com/q/431780/62483)

Comment: actually ipython is a shell and not a module. Tried `ipython` directly and it runs. thanks anyway!