# Why does updating and upgrading Ubuntu results in reverting the numpy version to 1.8.2

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, numpy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on a 64-bit machine.  I noticed that whenever I update and upgrade Ubuntu using sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade the numpy version in Python reverts back to 1.8.2.  Is this a coincidence or there is some systemic problem associated with Ubuntu upgrade.  Previously, I had numpy 1.9.2 installed.  Btw, Scipy, matplotlib, etc remain untouched.

Comment: *How* and to *where* in the filesystem did you install numpy 1.9.2?

Comment: I used pip in the following way:  sudo pip install numpy.  I don't know where in the file system does it install

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the [python-numpy package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-numpy) installed in Ubuntu, and you also installed the package using pip. You probably want to remove the python-numpy package. See [apt-get install vs pip install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install) for more information.