# python packages not updating with pip

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm a bit confused about `sudo apt-get install python-<package>` vs `sudo pip install` vs `pip install`. I have read many posts on the matter:

- [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip),
- [Is it acceptable & safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo),
- [apt-get install vs pip install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install)

My specific problem is that I have numpy 1.10.2. I try to update it with `pip install -U numpy`. It downloads 1.10.4, says it installs correctly, but when I do `pip show numpy` it's still 1.10.2. I'm worried that I have lots of versions everywhere because I wasn't aware of the difference between the installation methods. Also, I probably installed numpy with `sudo apt-get`, but then other scripts for other packages may have had scripts which `pip install` or `sudo pip install`. How can I see what's going on and how can I clean this up?

btw. `which pip` returns

```
/usr/bin/pip
```

`pip show numpy` returns

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.10.2
Location: /home/memo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'm getting the same problem with other packages such as SciPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I've found the problem. It's the pip that's in Ubuntu PPA, v1.5.6. Of course it's ultimately my user error, but that version of pip is really not forgiving. I wrote more about it on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725835/apt-get-install-python-xxx-vs-pip-install/725968#725968).