# Update-notifier-common & flashplugin-installer errors

Tags: 16.04, apt, lubuntu, flash, update-notifier

I'm new to Linux. I just dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 on a Windows 10 computer. Every time I try to install anything errors having to do with update-notifier-common and flashplugin-installer. Here is an example when I tried to install chrome:

```
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in  <module>
import debian.deb822

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in <module>
import chardet
ImportError: No module named 'chardet'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a follow up error from a previous failure.

Setting up chromium-browser (62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.16.04.1317) ...
Setting up chromium-browser-l10n (62.0.3202.94-0ubuntu0.16.04.1317) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Install the `python3-chardet` package.

Comment: I used `pip3 install chardet` and `pip install chardet` and both returned: `Requirement already satisfied: chardet in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages.`

Comment: Well, I suppose it says "`No module named 'chardet'`" for a reason. What about `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-chardet`?

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson. This works!

Comment: For anyone who has some kind of confusion, you can see this article [apt-get install vs pip install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and since i have installed alternative python version(3.6), and default version was(3.5), 
my solution was to `update-alternatives --config python3` to previous version just for the update .

hope it will help for others if they oncounter same problem.

Comment: I love you. Where is your tipping page?